# how to run python script located on a remote server

Tags: python-2.7

1. I have python script that I run on my cmd local machine.
2. now I want to run it also on a remote server(Windows)
   How can I do it?

Comment: First, the remote server must have python installed, and your script too.
Then use PSEXEC from sysinternals to run it remotely.

Comment: I tried it using wmi module:

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using ssh. Python accepts hyphen(-) as argument to execute the standard input,

```
cat hello.py | ssh user@192.168.1.101 python -
```

Run python --help for more info.

Comment: yes, but you have to install ssh on the server. On Windows you would probably use `putty` and `plink`, and you would have to type your password unless you handle auth keys properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ssh approach, but also the `PSEXEC` approach which is easier to use, although you may need admin privileges on the server to execute processes and both windows machines better share the same user/password.

Download PsExec from here

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649

Run as follows:

```
psexec /ACCEPTEULA \\servermachine python fullpath_to\python_script.py
```

`fullpath_to\python_script.py` should be accessible from the server. If not, you have to copy it first here, or just put the script on a shared/networked drive visible by both machines.
Of course python must be installed on the server as well.

I'm not saying it is the best way. Jenkins is a good way to run stuff on a given server. But it does the job.